# django "StringRelatedField.to_internal_value() must be implemented for field " error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model for a "gym", and a model for a "workout":

```
class Gym(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Workout(models.Model):
    gym = models.ForeignKey(Gym, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I will also show the 'WorkoutSerializer':

```
class WorkoutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    gym = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = Workout
        fields = ['gym','time']
```

as you can see, gym is represented in the workout json as a string of the field 'name'.

here is the view for workout:

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def workout_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = Workout.objects.select_related('gym').all() 
        serializer = WorkoutSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = WorkoutSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) # rasis 400 bad request if needed
        serializer.save()
        return Response('ok')
```

when I try to test a POST request with (**I want to use the gym's str representation in POST as well**):

{
"gym": "gym 2",
"activity": "Yuga",
"time": "2022-03-07T06:00:00Z",
"participants": [
"Anna Boing"
]
}

I get the error:

```
StringRelatedField.to_internal_value() must be implemented for field
```

any idea why, and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`StringRelatedField` is a read-only field. If you want to make `gym` field writable you can use [`SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) instead. Please note that the slug field corresponds to a model field with `unique=True`.

Comment: this is almost what I need. from the docs, it seems like slug field allows me to represent the target object by one of its fields - but I want to represent it with its string representation (\_\_str__). also, the values of this \_\_str__ rep are not necessarily unique - is that an issue?

Comment: @MoranReznik yes, it's a problem. You need unique representation, otherwise Django won't be able to find out what object it should use to keep relation in DB.

Answer (score 0):

I think **StringRelatedField** won't work for object creation,

Also, Gym needs an address and name both and you are just passing the name.

You can use **SlugRelatedField** for that.

Comment: this is almost what I need. from the docs, it seems like slug field allows me to represent the target object by one of its fields - but I want to represent it with its string representation (\_\_str__).  also, the values of this \_\_str__ rep are not necessarily unique - is that an issue?